# Get numeric return value from command

Tags: bash

In a bash shell if a command is successful it returns 0, and if unsuccessful it returns a another number. How do I get the number returned?

For example, I want the return code number returned from the `ls` command

I try:

```
echo $ls
echo $(ls)
echo $(?ls)
```

But none give me what I am looking for. Any tips?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After running a command, the `$?` variable will contain the command's exit code.

```
# This prints 0..
ls; echo $?

# .. and this prints 1
(exit 1); echo $?
```

Comment: The variable is called `?`, placing the `$` operator on the LHS gives the value.

Comment: Fair point, thanks. Worth noting is that it's not assignable like other variables (at least not through any basic testing I tried).

Answer (score 2):

The special variable `$?` contains the previous command's return status.

For example:

```
ls
echo $?
false
echo $?
```

Note that if you run another command before checking `$?`, its value will be that of the new command:

```
false
echo $? # prints the return status of false
echo $? # now prints the return status of the previous echo
```

So if you wish to use the status more than once, save it to a variable (e.g., `err=$?`).

Comment: The special variable is called `?`, placing the `$` operator on the LHS gives the value.

Comment: @cdarke True, but in the context I think it's clearer to say `$?`.